# How to print malloc size function with perf probe

Tags: trace, perf

I want to trace my program to understand memory allocation of my program. The idea is whenever malloc is called, it print out call stack with allocated `size`. 
This is command I used to create event:

```
perf probe -x /lib64/libc.so.6 'malloc allocated=-8(%bp):u64'
```

but `perf report` show me that `allocated` memory by this event is not correct. How can I fix this.

I think the problem is offset to `size` (`-8(%bp)`) is not correct. But I don't know asm so I can not understand libc binary.

UPDATE: With simple program, like:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    malloc(i);
```

then I can see the result is correct if I compiled with `O0`. The result when I compiled with `O3` is not correct. And with my big program (hundred thousand lines of code), compiled with `O0` but it can not give me the correct result.

Comment: Where does your `libc.so.6` come from? What's your `perf`/kernel version?

Comment: My system is CentOS 7.4. I don't remember if I changed libc version but I think I got it from CentOS standard repo. My kernel version is 3.10

Comment: @PhạmVănThông if you are still looking for an answer to this question - can you show the output of `perf report` and what are the discrepancies in the sizes allocated by **malloc** ? How much memory does the application allocate and how much is `perf report` actually showing ? Please add these details...

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita Sorry but I can not post the result here because I worked on VDI desktop (no internet connection) and it does not let me copy. But the result of `perf report` is look like normal but incorrect `allocated` size (the allocated size is too big or negative).  

P/S: I done it by installed debug-info package of glibc

Comment: Have you tried this with a newer kernel/`perf` version ? It is suggested in the `perf probe` man-pages to perform `perf probe` experiments with relatively newer linux kernels.

Comment: I did it by install debug-info package for `libc`

Answer (score 5):

Just take the argument from the `rdi` register instead of looking at the frame?

```
perf probe -x /lib64/libc.so.6 'malloc allocated=%di:u64'
```

On X86, use `eax` register instead:

```
perf probe -x /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 'malloc allocated=%ax:u32'
```

Comment: Yup, looks plausible, x86-64 SysV passes the first arg in RDI.  The other option would be `ltrace -e malloc` instead of perf at all.